# Style stripe payment element layout - get rid of stripe grid system

Tags: css, stripe-payments, customization

I'm trying to configure the [stripe payment element](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/appearance-api) for a custom design.

From what I could see, the only option I have is to use the [Elements Appearance API](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/appearance-api)

That's because stripe dynamically inserts an iframe with the markup (to remain PCI DSS compliant), and that's why I can't find a way to modify it.

Stripe payment element generates the following markup

```
<div class="p-Grid p-CardForm">
  <div class="p-GridCell p-GridCell--12 p-GridCell--md6">
    <!-- CardNumberInput -->
  </div>
  <div class="p-GridCell p-GridCell--6 p-GridCell--md3">
    <!-- expiryInput -->
  </div>
  <div class="p-GridCell p-GridCell--6 p-GridCell--md3">
    <!-- cvcInput -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Which uses some custom stripe grid system and produces this:

[image]

And above md it displays the following (it's applying the `p-GridCell--mdXX` classes):

[image]

I need to keep the first layout regardless the size of the viewport.

How can I disable stripe grids or choose what classes to apply?

---

**Update**: I tried the following approaches to modify the classes being applied, with no success:

1. Use javascript to inject a `style` tag to the iframe's head:

```
const iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]; // this works
const doc = iframe.contentDocument; // woops, this is always null!!!
doc.body.innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML + '<style>.....' // so I can't do something like this
```

(taken from [this article](https://redstapler.co/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe/))

2. Use javascript to get a reference to the container divs and modify the classes being applied (this approach works in the developer console, only after you inspect the element, but it doesn't work from a javascript block from the html page hosting the iframe)

```
const numberInput = document.getElementById('Field-numberInput'); // returns null

const numberContainer = document.querySelector('.p-GridCell.p-GridCell--12.p-GridCell--md6'); // also returns null
```

3. Following [this guide](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentdocument.asp) I also tried:

```js
const iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]; // this works
let y = iframe.contentWindow.document;
y.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Which throws the following error:

> FormElement.svelte:28 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
>
> at HTMLButtonElement.updateStyle

Answer (score 1):

I dont know stripe-payment css file but maybe changing md6 to md12 and md3 to md6 will work.

```
<div class="p-Grid p-CardForm">
  <div class="p-GridCell p-GridCell--12 p-GridCell--md12">
    <!-- CardNumberInput -->
  </div>
  <div class="p-GridCell p-GridCell--6 p-GridCell--md6">
    <!-- expiryInput -->
  </div>
  <div class="p-GridCell p-GridCell--6 p-GridCell--md6">
    <!-- cvcInput -->
  </div>
</div>
```

will work

Comment: Yes, from the developer console it works, the problem is that the markup is inside an iframe and I can't find a way to update it. See the information I added to the question

Comment: where did the css file of stripe stored in your project ? maybe you won't change the class name but class itself inside css file

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentdocument.asp

Comment: It's all being dinamycally generated by stripe.js library.
The iframe and the css is hosted on stripe site itself, like `https://js.stripe.com/v3/elements-inner-payment-fxxxd1.html` and `https://js.stripe.com/v3/fingerprinted/css/elements-inner-payment-6fxxxe7.css`

Comment: I followed your article and got a cross-origin error. Please have a look at 3) in the question

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/appearance-api#others check this document please,  if we can reach elements by using their class names like in Rules section(document) probably we can inspect css properties in that element first in browsers inspect tab and then we can change md-6 and md-3 properties

Comment: And i am a beginner in javascript so if you maybe ask this problem in javascript tag probably somebody can find a solution